# Running a VM in Azure just to download to a storage account

Tags: azure, browser, azure-storage

I am doing some work in Azure that requires downloading large files from the internet (data sets). We made a VM, basically, to run a browser to download files to our storage account.

Is there a "browser as a service" that would let me just get a data file from a URL to an Azure Storage account?

Comment: Is the data you're downloading publicly available i.e. is it possible to access this data directly without any authentication?

Comment: Generally, but I cannot tell if they check that you are in a browser before allowing a download.

Comment: But do you have to login to access this data?

Comment: Yes, in some cases there is a form you fill in before you get the download.

Answer (score 2):

If the data you're accessing is publicly available, then you don't need to set up a VM so that you can download this data and upload it in the storage. Azure Storage will do it for you.

Azure Blob Storage offers [`Async Copy`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob/) functionality which can read the data from any publicly accessible URL and copies this data asynchronously in blob storage. If you're using Windows, you can use [`AzCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) utility to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a WebJob (a background service that can be run in the context of an App Service). You can run scripts in it that can hit the URL, download the file and store it in the Storage Account